# How to update input value reflecting the current value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a slider with a tooltip showing the updated value when the thumb is moved either by dragging or by clicking plus/minus button.

It works fine, but when I click plus/minus button AFTER dragging thumb it jumps to another position instead of continuing from where it is. How can I fix it to reflect the last value? Here's fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2q1rg56z/12/.

```
var update_num = $('output').text() * 1;

$('.plus').on('click', function() {
    if (update_num < 100) {
        $('output').text(++update_num);
        $('input').val(update_num).trigger('input');
    } else {
        $('output').text(100);
    }
});

$('.minus').on('click', function() {
    if (update_num > 0) {
        $('output').text(--update_num);
        $('input').val(update_num).trigger('input');
    } else {
        $('output').text(0);
    }
});
```

(It seems that the latest value should be stored in a var, so what should be the best way to do it?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have almost given the answer yourself. Whenever the slider is used, you have to update the variable `update_num`.

In your fiddle there is already the handler to do this:

```
$('.range-control > input').on('input', function() { 
    var value = this.value;
    //...
```

So you only have to pull up your `update_num` so you can access it from the scope of the slider input handler and set it the `value`.

I updated the fiddle to make it work:
https://jsfiddle.net/2q1rg56z/14/

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Perfect. update_num= value; was the way to connect input value into output. Simple and neat, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this line only runs once:

```
var update_num = $('output').text() * 1;
```

You should turn it into a function

```
var update_num = function() { return +$('output').text(); };
```

Now call it in your code:

```
if (update_num() < 100) {
  /***/
}
```

See this **[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2q1rg56z/16/)**

**Side Note:** Note my use of `+` to convert a string to an integer.See http://www.jstips.co/en/converting-to-number-fast-way/

Comment: True, still I needed to connect input value to output and lext82's solution worked out. Thanks for your suggestion anyway!

Comment: No problem. The problem of coupling your data model to the gui whic you are running into is a classic problem that js frameworks are working hard to solve so you may want to check out angular and react (the big and popular ones) to see the sort of stuff they are doing.

Comment: Agreed, frameworks are the way to go to handle two way binding. But the whole point of this challenge was to solve it with vanilla JS/jQuery, so I get to learn the mechanism behind it. Also saw that I missed adding () to var after making it function, so that's why it didn't' work out previously. Now I see it works great as your jsfiddle shows. Thanks a lot, this is a great alternative way to make it work as well!